# Nuxt 3 (Vue.js 3) component transitions not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, transition, nuxtjs3

I want to transition (from the right) a dynamic component in Nuxt v3 when the content changes. The component is working as required, but I can't get the transition to work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--- other HTML -->
    <transition name="left-to-right" mode="out-in" :key="currentScreenIndex">
      <QuestionsWrap :question="questionScreens[currentScreenIndex]" :key="currentScreenIndex" />
    </transition>
    <!--- other HTML -->
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .left-to-right-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  .left-to-right-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: `transition` is for a single one, otherwise you may use `transition-group`.

Comment: The answer below works perfectly without using `transition-group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `:key` from the `Transition`. I think this is what's stopping the rendering entirely.

Then, you'll want to add your `leave-to` and `leave-from` css properties.

This should do the trick:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--- other HTML -->
    <transition name="left-to-right" mode="out-in">
      <QuestionsWrap :question="questionScreens[currentScreenIndex]" :key="currentScreenIndex" />
    </transition>
    <!--- other HTML -->
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .left-to-right-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  }
  .left-to-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  .left-to-right-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  }
  .left-to-right-enter-from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked a treat. Thank you. Heads up for anyone else, that `scoped` does work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `scoped` attribute from style:

```html
<style>
  .left-to-right-enter-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  .left-to-right-leave-active {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
</style>
```

Remember Nuxt match css clases and scoped add extra id on compile.

Comment: Thanks. Good point about `scoped`. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: Having scoped CSS is important tho. That one should be a concrete decision and not a fallback all-in-one solution. Here, that may be a good fit if the transition is used elsewhere, otherwise, there is no point.